# Eloquent nesting with clause in the middle relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested

I have the following relationships:

- User [many-to-many with] Assignments
- Assignments [many-to-many with] Badges
- The assignment_user pivot table has a flag 'is_finished' which I need to be true

These are my relationships in the matching models:

User.php

```
public function assignments()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Assignment')->withPivot('is_finished')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Assignment.php

```
public function badges()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Badge', 'badge_assignment')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Badge.php

```
public function assignments()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Assignment', 'badge_assignment')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I'm trying to get all the Badges for my User's finished Assignments. This was my query:

```
$user = User::with(array(
'assignments' => function($query) {
$query->where('is_finished', '=', true)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
})
)
->with('badges')
->username($name)->first();
```

However this is rendering the error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::badges()" when I use foreach($user->assignments->badges ...).

I then tried to get badges inside the scope of the first with, but I don't know how to reach is_finished:

```
$user = User::with(array(
'assignments.badges' => function($query) {
$query->where('is_finished', '=', true)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
})
)
->username($name)->first();
```

With this I get "column not found", because the query is looking for is_finished within the badges, not the assignment_user relationship.

As I was having this issue I tried this just to be sure:

```
User::with('assignments.badges')->whereUsername($username);
```

... and I'm still getting "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$badges".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load nested `assignments.badges` like this:

```
$user = User::with(array(
    'assignments' => function($query) {
      $query->where('is_finished', '=', true)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    })
  )
  ->with('assignments.badges')
  ->username($name) // do you have a scope for this or should it be whereUsername?
  ->first();
```

Comment: using your code renders the same error as my third (simple) attempt: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$badges".

FYI, I am using $user->assignments->badges in my view after fetching the results from the query.

Comment: I don't think it does. You are probably trying to call something like this: `$user->assignments->badges` and it obviously  will throw this error. For the eager loading itself, my code is the way to go, trust me. Well, yeah, you can't do that of course - you want to fetch `model's` relation on the `collection` of models - you need a foreach loop for example.

Comment: Silly me, of course you are right. I was being stupid and trying to fetch badges without running a second loop for each assignment. Thanks a lot for the quick solution!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this work for a 3-level deep nesting? I can't just use with('table1.table2.table3') - how would it work?

Comment: You can use dot-nested relations as you like, so yes `relation1.relation2.relation3 ....` will work (it's not table1 etc, but relations names like in your models).

Comment: Yes, the word table was a bad choice, but I understand your point. Thanks again!